# How to solve it without integrals: $ \sum_{k=1}^{n} \sin{\left(\frac{k\pi}{n}\right)}\sin{\left(\frac{k\pi}{n^2 }\right)}$

Tags: trigonometry

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n} \sin{\left(\frac{k\pi}{n}\right)}\sin{\left(\frac{k\pi}{n^2 }\right)}$$
I tried writing the product as a difference of cosine but it s not so good.

Comment: What's your question ? Finding the limit, or a closed form for that sum ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINTS:**
Use the identity
$$\sin(x)\sin(y)=\frac12\cos(x-y)-\frac12\cos(x+y)$$
and then use the fact the 
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \cos(ak)=\csc(a/2)\sin(an/2)\cos(a(n+1)/2)$$

where $a$ does not depend on $k$, but can certainly depend on $n$.

Comment: Thank you Mark Viola. That s the way I did it too. I thought there could be a tricky solution

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.